# How to run a Ext GWT (GXT) application with Maven

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am trying to make a GXT 3.0 starting app with Maven support. I have successfully compiled and run the native GWT application with `mvn gwt:compile gwt:run` command

Howeven, when I added these dependecies:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
 <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
 <version>${gxt.version}</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gxt-uibinder</artifactId>
    <version>${gxt.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gxt-chart</artifactId>
    <version>${gxt.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
    <artifactId>uibinder-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and added this in the gwt.xml (module) file:

```
<inherits name="com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT" />
```

I am getting this error (running the same mvn command as above):

```
GWT module com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT not found
```

And looking from the Java build path of the project in the `Maven Dependencies`, I can see that the GXT jars have not been downloaded.

[Full pom.xml here.](http://pastebin.com/Z7SsRX0y)

Comment: BTW, for the GXT version I have this in the POM: <gxt.version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</gxt.version>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the snapshot, make sure you have the repository tags for it as well, for wherever you are getting that build from. Otherwise use the latest release, `3.0.0-beta3`.

If you are building your own local copies, or deploying to an internal repo, then 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT should work - make sure the jar can be found in your repo, and that you aren't running as offline.

Comment: Also, uibinder-bridge should match your GWT version, 2.4.0. After 2.4, the code in there is in GWT trunk, so that jar is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

GXT does not require `uibinder-bridge` anymore [according to Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246246-uibinder-bridge-for-GWT-2.5.0).
All GXT uibinder features were incorporated into GWT 2.5.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

GXT 3.0.1 is on maven central

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```